# Regex to ignore multilines in between strings and select specific lines

Tags: regex

I have a sample like this where I wants to get only Name ,Address Phone and Email lines from Contact Info section

** Site Info **

Name: BBB

Address: EFG Street

Country: IN

** Contact Info **

Name: ABC

Company: PQR

Address: EFG Street

Country: IN

Phone: 12345

Email: llcd@gmail.com

Occupation: XYZ

I tried to use -->(?<=Customer Supplied Site Info *{2}[\n\r]).*[*\n\r]*Name:\s*([^\n\r]*) and this is working only for Name. Anyone could help me here to find proper regex for remaining fields as well

Comment: Could you please re-format the question using backticks? And please add the language tag. Your regex [does not do](https://regex101.com/r/ZdGRyX/1) what you claim it does.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches using `python` to get the results as a `dict` for every person.

```
data = """** Site Info **

Name: BBB

Address: EFG Street

Country: IN

** Contact Info **

Name: ABC

Company: PQR

Address: EFG Street

Country: IN

Phone: 12345

Email: llcd@gmail.com

Occupation: XYZ
"""
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(dict)
got_contact_info = False
name = None
for line in data.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if 'Contact Info' in line:
        got_contact_info = True
        continue
    if not got_contact_info:
        continue
    
    if 'Name' in line:
        name = line.split(':')[1]
    elif 'Address' in line:
        out[name]['Address']=line.split(':')[1].strip()
    elif 'Phone' in line:
        out[name]['Phone']=line.split(':')[1].strip()
    elif 'Email' in line:
        out[name]['Email']=line.split(':')[1].strip()
print (out)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {' ABC': {'Address': 'EFG Street', 'Phone': '12345', 'Email': 'llcd@gmail.com'}})
```

Comment: It is not written OP uses Python, why do you think it will help?

Comment: Oh, saw it due to my filters on SO which contains python,regex filter and hence saw this question. Missed to check the tags which OP has added

Comment: @BhagyeshDudhediya Thank you so much for checking this. Actually I am trying to solve it using regex and to extract values